# How to use monkeytalk test script in multiple subfolders ? I have created folders like Login, Logout in one project

Tags: monkeytalk

I have a situation where i created one project [MonkeytalkProject1] and there i have added multiple folders like Login, Logout. Now, i have written script for login.mt and logout.mt. I want to use logout.mt script in login.mt script in this way [Script louout.mt Run]. but when i run login.mt scrpt then it won't logout and giving me error as [Logout.mt source not found] It would be great if someone help me. Also, please let me know proper test design structure that i need to follow while creating a project in MonkeyTalk ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using TestLibrary.
As stated, you want to use Logout folder scripts in Login folder then you just need to select all required script from Logout folder and right click then select New -> Testlibrary. Now select the source folder [Login] where you want to create library by giving some logical name like TestLibrary_Logout.mtl

Now you can call logout.mt script in login.mt as

```
Script louout.mt Run
```

Happy Automation !!

Refer [This for more details](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Monkeytalk works on flat directory structure, so you can't call a script from another folder.

Put your login and logout as a separate functions in a js file and include that js in your script file and then call those functions as needed

Comment: Thanks @Balaji Sekar: But case is like suppose i have multiple actions like opening popover, closing popover, tapping on email address or password field or tapping a particular element. And, i want to use these components again and again in sevaral scripts then in that case should i need to add all functions in separate js file and then include. Also, i tried to use [link]https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/content/monkeytalk-hacking-wanna-share-my-js-stuffs but it didn't work.

Comment: @user3815836 Yes. Add all the needed code in a js file and include them in other script files and call the required functions. Thats the only solution I could think of.